# Can one access object position from previous frame in geometry nodes?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I'm working on a music visualizer. I baked the sound of a kick drum to an empty's z axis. I would like to access the position of the empty, of both the current frame and a previous frame or earlier point in time, in order to animate an object to visualize the sound. I know how to access the empty's current position, in order to affect the position of my visualizer object. However, can I also access the position of the empty a few frames earlier? I would like to create a "ghosting" effect, where a semi-transparent copy of my visualizer follows the original visualizer. In other words, the copy should be a few frames behind the original. Is this possible in geometry nodes?

Comment: No. No past history is available at a frame. unless you have a way to calculate the old position you can’t access it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a way to pass information between different frames. But this may help:

Duplicate your empty. Shift the animation of the duplicate on the time line and use the duplicate for animating the ghost.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I was thinking that I had to do something like this, outside of geometry nodes. Hopefully access to time can be incorporated in everything nodes soon.